# Сумма значений, дата которых попадает в указанный период

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet

Существует таблица с заказами товаров...
[image: Заказы]

И существует другая таблица с двумя полями дат...
[image: Период дат]

Есть функцияция `SUMIF()`, которая подсчитывает сумму чисел по условному выражению. Пробовал по разному, но выдает ошибку.

Мои варианты функции:

```
=SUMIF('Замовлення'!A2:A;"<"&C6 AND ">"&E6;'Замовлення'!E2:E)

=SUMIF('Замовлення'!A2:A;"<"&C6)
```

Помогите разобратся с синтаксисом написания

Answer (score 0):

Надо проверять два условия - сравнение с двумя датами. `SUMIF` же принимает только одно...

```
"<"&C6 AND ">"&E6
```

В Вашем сравнении две ошибки: синтаксическая (так условие нельзя писать), и логическая (хотите посчитать значения, даты которых находятся за пределами диапазона - все, что меньше нижней границы и больше верхней).

Есть ее младшая сестричка этой функции, которой можно задавать множество условий:

```
=SUMIFS('Замовлення'!E2:E;'Замовлення'!A2:A;">="C6;'Замовлення'!A2:A;"<="E6)
```

Еще одно отличие - в `SUMIF` слева диапазон условия, справа диапазон суммирования, в  `SUMIFS` сначала пишется диапазон суммирования.

А вот функция `SUMPRODUCT` не смотрит на очередность, можно хоть так:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('Замовлення'!A2:A<=E6);'Замовлення'!E2:E;--('Замовлення'!A2:A>=C6))
```

Это только как пример, на практике так писать не рекомедую, правильно - по-порядку, чтобы легче читалась формула.